# Pyplot won't let me create a plot with more than ~7280 points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a scatterplot with about 10k points:

```
from random import shuffle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Dataset of numbers up to 10k
numbers = range(10000)
shuffle(numbers)
xvalues, yvalues = zip(*list(enumerate(numbers)))

plt.scatter(yvalues, xvalues)
plt.xscale("log")
plt.show()
```

But I get the error:

> Assertion failed: (transform_is_valid(m)), function CGMutablePathRef CGPathCreateMutableCopyByTransformingPath(CGPathRef, const CGAffineTransform *), file Paths/CGPath.cc, line 168.
>   Abort trap: 6

If I reduce the number of points to around 7284 it works though!

```
xvalues, yvalues = zip(*list(enumerate(numbers[:7284])))
```

Why?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. What Python and `matplotlib` version are you running?

Comment: update your matplotlib

Comment: I can't reproduce either. I'm running Anaconda2-4.0.0

Comment: Yep just needed an upgrade (1.3.1 to 2.0.2 lol) - @eyllanesc can you post that as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade your version of `matplotlib`